# Tracking an error in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to create a loop for some data that:

1. takes all the data for a certain `Date`
2. uses an interpolation function `dpinterp` to calculate interpolation within that `Date`
3. Plot the data for each date and outputs it as a file. I am ok with this step and thus will not include it here. I mention it simply to illustrate why I am using a loop in this case.

Packages and function:

```
library(akima)
library(dplyr)


dpinterp <- function(df=df) {
  interp_df <- interp(x=df$x, y=df$y, z=df$x, duplicate="mean")
  interp2xyz(interp_df, data.frame=TRUE)
}
```

Data creation:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=runif(4000,1,400),
  y=runif(4000,10,40),
  z=runif(4000,10,40),
  Date=seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1910/1/4"), "days"))
```

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce my error with the above data set but for this example I don't think it matters. What I would like to know is if I try to run the loop below and I receive an error, how do I track which `Date` this error occurred on?

```
day <- unique(df$Date)

diagdf <- c()
for (i in day)
{
  u <- df %>%
    filter(Date %in% i) %>%
    do(dpinterp(.)) %>%
    ungroup() 

  diagdf <- rbind(diagdf, u)
  diagdf$Date <- as.Date(i, origin="1970-01-01")
}
tbl_df(diagdf)
```

I realize that something like this is equivalent:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  do(dpinterp(.))
```

However, I do not know how to traceback errors in a `dplyr` pipe.

So the basic questions is, with all the above for context, is how do I traceback errors within a loop to figure what `Date` and giving me problems?

**Edit**

Here is the error I receive:

> Error in interp.old(x, y, z, xo = xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap =
>   extrap,  :    all data collinear Called from: interp.old(x, y, z, xo =
>   xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap = extrap, 
>       duplicate = duplicate, dupfun = dupfun) Browse[1]>

That is fine, some of the data appears to be collinear. But my issue is which data are throwing the error? Here are the results of a traceback:

```
traceback()

18: stop("all data collinear")
17: interp.old(x, y, z, xo = xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap = extrap, 
        duplicate = duplicate, dupfun = dupfun)
16: interp(x = df$Pos, y = df$depth, z = df$value, duplicate = "mean") at #2
15: dpinterp(.)
14: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
13: eval(x$expr, data, x$env)
12: lazyeval::lazy_eval(args[[1]], data)
11: do_.data.frame(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
10: do_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
9: do(., dpinterp(.))
8: function_list[[k]](value)
7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1: ktlpltdf %>% filter(variable %in% c(j)) %>% filter(Date == as.Date(i, 
       origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% mutate(Pos = ifelse(Station == 
       "KLF1", 1, ifelse(Station == "KLF7", 3, 2))) %>% do(dpinterp(.)) at #5
```

Comment: What is the error?  Also, you may want to think about this problem using an `apply` family function.  You generally don't want to use `for` loops and `rbind` the results.

Comment: I'd throw in one or two `print(i, "number 1")` and `print(i, "number 2")` type statements.

Comment: @lmo Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I may have misread your problem, but my suggestion was something like `for(i in day) {; cat(i, "number 1"); ... dplyr stuff ungroup(); cat(i, "number 2");` I switched to `cat` because it avoid a `paste` call.

Comment: @lmo. That is helpful. Any idea how to format `cat` so that it outputs a date rather than an integer?

Comment: Include the origin argument in `as.Date`. For example: `as.Date(35, origin="1970-1-1")` prints  "1970-02-05".  1 January, 1970 is 1 for as.Date. You would use `cat(as.Date(i, origin="1970-1-1"), "number 2")` if your dates are date types in R.

Comment: @lmo I did try that. It still print them as numbers like "12940 number 1 12940 number 2". Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `cat(as.Date(as.integer(i), origin="1970-1-1"), "number 2")` will work?

Comment: @lmo I ended up factorizing the date before the loop. That worked well. This was a great answer if you want to put as such I could accept it and you could get credit.

Comment: Sure thing, @boshek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tried and true method for solving problems that occur in a loop is to print out the incrementor during each iteration in the `for` loop.

You could try something like

```
for(i in day) {
  # first print out
  cat(i, "number 1") 

  ... dplyr stuff ungroup()

  # print a successful run through the `dplyr` chain
  cat(i, "number 2")

  ... other stuff
}
```

By adding multiple print statements that have a slightly different message, you can see where in the body of the loop the problem is occurring.